# Why is AppDelegate.swift window an optional?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, uiwindow

I was reading [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html), when I found this sentence:

> The `AppDelegate` class contains a single property: `window`.
>
> `var window: UIWindow?`
>
> This property stores a reference to the app’s window. This window
> represents the root of your app’s view hierarchy. It is where all of
> your app content is drawn. Note that the window property is an
> [optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/GlossaryDefinitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH12-SW11), which means it may have no value (be [nil](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/GlossaryDefinitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH12-SW5)) at some point.

What I don't understand is: why this property at some point could be nil? What's the case for it to be(come) nil?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you close your application, your app can still receive [silentNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) or download data **in the background**, track your location, play music, etc.

In the images below, the encircled *red* [image]  are for when your app is still *doing* something, however it is no longer *on* the screen. It's in the background, so `AppDelegate` doesn't need a `window` anymore. As a result it will be set to `nil`

## Simple overview

[image]

---

## Detail overview

[image]

FWIW, the code below **won't** make the app launch with `vc`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let vc = ViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = vc
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

Why it doesn't work? Because the `window` property is an optional—initially set to nil.**It needs to be instantiated**

The code below will work

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let vc = ViewController()
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds) // Now it is instantiated!!
    window?.rootViewController = vc
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may not always need it. For example, when these two methods are called :

```
application(_:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)
application(_:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:)
```

your app will not be shown to the user, so there is no need for a `window`.

As always, more in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/)

Now, I'm not sure that this is the inherent reason, but it seems as a good enough possibility (at least for me). Though if someone is able to provided some more information, I'd gladly learn some more also.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. What it feels strange is the fact that, the way it is described, it looks like there's always a window but at some point, under certain circumstances, it could be nil. This surprises me a little, since that window should be a sort of root, the first place your app uses to draw its contents (even if your app performs background actions, I suppose)

Comment: Well, these methods in particular are called when your app is inactive - i.e. the user is not using it at the moment - he may be using another app or not even using his phone at the moment. Then, there is no need to use more resources than needed - especially with the fact that you have limited processing time to finish your work (~30 seconds).

Comment: is there any way to test, when these methods are called, if window is nil?

Comment: Well, logging to console may be a problem :) I suppose you could write a value to `NSUserDefaults` when `window == nil` and then when running the app simply retrieve the value and either log it in console or in a label.

Answer (score 4):

It becomes more obvious when you create the window programmatically instead of using a main storyboard, which automatically sets the `window` property.

You may not want to or not be able to create the window immediately when your delegate object (`AppDelegate` in your case) is created. Usually you don't need to create the window and set the property until `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` was called. So until the window is created and the property is set it will be `nil`.
Like Losiowaty [already stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34159492/1183577) this is also the case when the app is started but not displayed to the user - e.g. when just processing location updates or other information in the background.

If the property would be non-optional then you would be forced to create the window at the moment you create your `AppDelegate` object which is neither desired nor necessary.

Comment: That's an excellent point! I guess, I never though about `AppDelegate` having a normal object lifecycle - i.e. that there is an `init` somewhere before `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`, as it was usually considered an "entry point" to it.