# Why is "var delegate: UIApplicationDelegate?" made an optional in UIApplication? That'd be a fatal error?

Tags: swift, appdelegate

Were the `delegate` property ever to be `nil`, the app would be in an unrecoverable state.

> *class* **UIApplication**
>
> **Declaration**
> unowned(unsafe) var delegate: UIApplicationDelegate?
> **Discussion**
> Every app must have an app delegate object to respond to app-related messages. For example, the app notifies its delegate when the app finishes launching and when its foreground or background execution status changes. Similarly, app-related messages coming from the system are often routed to the app delegate for handling. Xcode provides an initial app delegate for every app and you should not need to change this delegate later.

Why is `UIApplicationDelegate.delegate` defined as an optional?  A `nil` value would be non-recoverable?

Actually, if I were to subclass *UIApplication* then I might be able to recover from `delegate` set to `nil`? Is this maybe why?

Here is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159160/why-is-appdelegate-swift-window-an-optional), but the `AppDelegate` is what holds the entire app together. I don't think it could be `nil`.

Comment: Delegate objects associated to protocols are optional by definition because they might be not connected. Of course the application must have an object adopting the `UI/NSApplicationDelegate` protocol and a distinct connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to know why/how this works you would have to know how UIApplication works internally, so any idea as to why or why not it's optional is purely conjecture.

There's likely a point where if the delegate is nil, the application either quits or crashes, or it's simply to allow initialization without setting the delegate and they chose not to force unwrap it so they can handle the error case.

Answer (score 5):

One reason might be to prevent AppDelegate from messing up with your unit tests.

Normally, when you are running unit tests, you actually don't ever have to interact with any UI components drawn onto screen so, initializing application's `window` property is totally unnecessary. Moreover, the code written in `AppDelegate.swift` (such as function calls in `application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`) might cause your unit tests to not run as intended so you may want the application delegate to never be instantiated.

For a typical iOS application, UIKit creates the application with the following function in `main.swift`:

```
UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, 
  NSStringFromClass(UIApplication), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

*(As of Xcode 6, it is handled by the [`@UIApplicationMain`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516250/what-does-uiapplicationmain-mean) decorator.)*

`UIApplicationMain` initializes the application object and the application delegate whose type is the class name you passed to it, and sets up the event cycle. It's totally up to you to have it create the delegate object for you. If you don't need AppDelegate's `UIWindow` property, or any callback methods about handling push notifications, application's state etc., you create the application without it:

```
UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, NSStringFromClass(UIApplication), nil)
```

So that being said, if your unit tests don't depend on any of AppDelegate's methods to run, you can update `main.swift` as follows:

```
var delegateClassName: String? = NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate)

if NSClassFromString("XCTestCase") != nil {
 // Unit tests are being run, so don't execute any code written in AppDelegate.swift
 delegateClassName = nil
}
UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, NSStringFromClass(UIApplication), delegateClassName)
```

Comment: When the 4th argument of UIApplicationMain(...) is `nil`, that doesn't mean that there is no AppDelegate? Rather, `nil` means that the AppDelegate will be created using the main NIB file? I am probably misunderstanding because this is new to me.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the extra information. Normally, I rarely use .nib files in my projects so I missed that condition. I can say `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate` returns nil and no code is executed in AppDelegate.swift, if you don't use a main nib file and pass `nil` as the delegate parameter to `UIApplicationMain`.